# Can't drop file from Explorer anywhere (except to Explorer) on Windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, drag-and-drop

It's been now a week since I am not able to drag and drop file from the windows explorer. Basically, the mouse pointer becomes a  prohibited sign every time I am trying to drop a folder or a file anywhere else than onto an folder.

I have tried with iTunes (dropping a file/folder got me the  sign every time), in Mega website (through Google Chrome) and Photoshop as well, same result every where.

I was on the phone with a Microsoft Tech guy and he make me run some basic test just to tell me that my user profile was corrupt and I had to create a new one...

I already try to press a few key combination while drag-n-dropping but no change.

I really don't want to create a new user and have to copy every thing over.

I am running a legit Windows 10 Pro x64 freshly install ( a month ago maybe?).

EDIT:
No sure if it's relevant here, but I have check the MIME data while drag-n-dropping onto a small Qt project of mine and it's working fine, here is what I have:

[image: MIME Data of a dropped song]

Comment: A new user account is probably easier than fixing this issue.

Comment: Yes, this will be the last option tho because for majority of my apps I select install only for the current user. I just wanted to give that issue one last chance of being solved...

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-corrupted-user-profile#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have found a <s>solution</s> workaround by disabeling the UAC completly, which I don't really but meh.

To fully disable UAC, use regedit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Change `EnableLUA` from 1 to 0

Comment: Hmm. I'm curious how that would workaround the drag/drop issue ...

Comment: No idea either, put I'm pretty glad I don't to copy to another user or something :)!

Comment: @DavidPostill with UAC turned on you can only drag&drop to apps with the same privileges.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thx, good to know.